# Script execution order not working in Unity 4.6.1

Tags: time, unity-game-engine

My Unity seems to have a problem with script execution order. Whenever I try to change the script execution order, it does not work. You're supposed to click the "+" and a list of scripts will appear, so you can set which one executes before default time or after…

You can also drag and drop the scripts as you want. Neither of these ways work, because the "+" doesn't react when I click it and nothing happens either when I drag and drop the script. I've tried activating a 30 day pro trial version of Unity, I've tried reinstalling, changing the build platforms. Nothing seems to work. When I check on my friend's computer, the script execution order works perfectly. I would like to know how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: I'm also using Visual Studio 2014 instead of MonoDevelop, if that has aything to do with the problem.

Comment: Same issue here!!! Did you find a workaround?

Comment: It works in one of my projects, but not the other one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a known bug in Unity 4.6.1 that script execution order was ignored in some projects for no reason at all. This issue has long been fixed in Unity since then.